I adjusted the 5e Ghost. Am I calculating its CR correctly?
I'm making a modified version of the Ghost for 5e. I used the DMG guidelines on pages 274 onward.
When I went to calculate its defensive CR, I was astounded at how high it was. Am I making a mistake here?
150 HP starting + Possession ability (double the effective HP) + Horrifying Visage (+25% effective HP if facing a group of characters from level 10 and lower. It is.) + HP Multiplier for immunities (CR 6 = x2) = 750 effective Hit Points. I didn't even include resistances. Without taking into account the AC, this makes its defensive CR 28.
Even if I cut that in half to determine overall CR (assuming Offensive CR is 0), it would be a CR 14 monster.
Am I missing something here? Am I calculating this wrong?

Why did you started from 150 HPs? A ghost has only 45 HPs.

It's meant to be a boss fight for the PC's and possibly a solo boss. Whatever the case, even when I reduced the HP, it was still pretty high on the defensive CR. I had to reduces it to...I think 49 hp just to make it a cr 6 or cr7

So you aren't considering the vanilla ghost: you should point this modification, and not just state "I'm making a modified version". Recall also that the CR of creatures in MM does not follow the DMG rules..

@Eddymage It generally does follow. There are exceptions, but not enough to say right out that the MM CRs don’t follow the CR calculations of the DMG.

@ThomasMarkov yep, my comment lacks an "always" between "not" and "follow"... Forgot it!

The CR guidelines are only guidelines. They can be inaccurate, especially when you go to some extreme.
You probably shouldn't be using the CR 6 multiplier for immunities for something with that much raw hp, let alone with features that increase it's effective HP. I would also err on having the multipliers apply to the base HP, as the DMG doesn't give guidance on how to apply multiple multipliers.
You are also ignoring AC in calculating the defensive CR, the regular ghost's AC of 11 is well below a CR4 monster. Using the table on DMG274, we can see that the MM ghost has something like 4/11ths HP compared to the baseline of CR4.
I think you need to figure out approximately what CR you want this to be, and then work backwards from that to find an appropriate increase of HP over the listed ghost. E.g. if you want a CR8 monster, something like 67HP seems appropriate, assuming you also increase the damage output.

Good shout on mentioning the AC and health pool. Ultimately, that will make a big difference in being able to dispatch a Ghost! :)

First, keep in mind that CR is not a hard science, it's a guideline that should help a DM to roughly balance how tanky and dangerous a monster can be at which level. If it produces absurd results, you absolutely should ignore it.
But I think you might not have correctly applied the Resistances and Immunities multiplier. The DMG specifically says:

If a monster has resistance or immunity to several damage types especially bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing damage from nonmagical weapons and not all the characters in the party possess the means to counteract that resistance or immunity, you need to take these defenses into account when comparing your monster's hit points to its expected challenge rating.

Emphasis mine. Just having immunity doesn't blanket double your effective HP. You should keep in mind the specific party you're creating this monster for. Does everyone have a magic weapon? Then the resistance to nonmagic weapons has no effect and you can ignore it. The ghost has immunity to necrotic damage, but is necrotic damage a significant part of your party's damage output? If not, it won't impact how hard the monster really is to kill.
